# Is there a way to track internal Firebase bugs/issues/feature-requests?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, issue-tracking

Is there a way to track internal Firebase bugs/issues/feature-requests?

By "internal" I mean those not part of the open-source portion of Firebase's codebase tracked on GitHub.

I have a tracking number for the issue – `b/148360318` – but it yields no results in Google's Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/

The only Firebase service I've been able to find there is Firestore; but this issue relates to Auth Server behavior. As far as I can tell, the Issue Tracker only has Cloud Platform issues.

Email support doesn't provide such notifications (the advice is to read release notes), but unfortunately that isn't a substitute because there will be no indication if it's been abandoned (in which case I'd need to work around it).

Without being able to track the issue, I'm not sure how to be notified if/when it's been addressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no external mechanism to track internal support cases with Firebase support.  You will have to stay in contact with them over their the email support system, or they will have to expose an internal bug as an external bug visible through issuetracker.google.com.

Comment: Agreed with Doug. You will need to ask the source (where you got the b/148360318), for an issue link visible for public. You can then star that public issue where you will get updates regarding the internal opened issue that is being worked on.